# MySQL SQL script not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbye in MySQL (comming from SQLServer) and I have an syntax error with the following code (which I could use in SQLServer) and, looking in the manual, I haven't discovered the problem yet:

```
UPDATE t002_produto as p
   SET (p.prd_cod=111,
        p.prd_prod=1,
        p.prd_modal=222,
        p.prd_nome='Produto Teste 1',
        p.prd_abrev='Prod',
        p.prd_tipo='Prod',
        p.prd_bndes=1);

prd_cod = BIGINT(20) PK NN
prd_cod = BIGINT(20) NN
prd_modal = BIGINT(20)
prd_nome = VARCHAR(50)
prd_abrev = VARCHAR(10)
prd_tipo = VARCHAR(15)
prd_bndes = BIT(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the parenthesis are not needed.
or maybe the AS is not allowed.
easy to check. I would do:

```
UPDATE 
    t002_produto
SET
   prd_cod=111,
   prd_prod=1, 
   prd_modal=222, 
   prd_nome='Produto Teste 1',
   prd_abrev='Prod',
   prd_tipo='Prod',
   prd_bndes=1
;
```

BEWARE that it will update all the table since you didn't write a WHERE clause.

Comment: That's it... very simple... Why not the guys unify the syntax of SQL, at least in basic operations? Thanks...

Comment: the problem was the parenthesis, AS is Ok. I'd forgot the WHERE clause, which is present in my code.

Comment: they do. it's microsoft that ignores the standards. :)